# get user details by not user's username, but by user's real name from twitter by tweepy in python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

In python, you can get user's details from twitter by the following code.

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.get_user('joseph')
```

"joseph" is a username, and I can get the user details by using "username" of the user.

How can I manage this by using "real name" of the user; e.g. instead on "joseph", by using "Joseph Kohen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `screen_name` parameter in the `get_user` method that allows you to search by the screen name.

try `user = api.get_user(screen_name='Joseph Kohen')`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a user's details using their real name, twitter users can change their real name at any time and multiple users can have identical display names.

The `screen_name` parameter of `get_user` in tweepy only works with usernames. Valid parameters for `get_user` are as follows:

> - id – Specifies the ID or screen name of the user.
> - user_id – Specifies the ID of the user. Helpful for disambiguating when a valid user ID is also a valid screen name.
> - screen_name – Specifies the screen name of the user. Helpful for disambiguating when a valid screen name is also a user ID.

From the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_user)

You can look up users by real name using [API.search_users](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.search_users), but this will return multiple users, and can't be reliably used to get a specific user.